# How to automate email verification link sent to inbox of the emailid entered for new user registration using selenium webdriver c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, mailinator

I have a web application which has a feature to register new user.a mail is sent to the entered email id.We have to take the verification code and enter in the web application.
My question is since we run tests multiple times , it is not possible to register the same user again and again. How to make it generalized since it is not possible to provide different new email ids and credentials everytime. 
I have an option of ' mailinator ' which is a free public mailbox but it is not secure. Is there any other alternative to handle this ? I am using .NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the alternatives might be:

1. Use a dispostable email system like mailinator(or others) and you can generate emails on the fly, they also have the option to get a private account.
2. Check if the current email used can support alias(i knew google did, but you might have issues in the future if the server thinks you are attacking due lot of requests)
3. Delete your email each time after the register scenario is done, I do not recommend this since it may fail if you are using the same email in other tests
4. Create your own email server

Best option would be the 1'st one, you can also use their api and you can make email interaction faster, and use a private account.

If you have a project it should not be a big deal to convince the client to pay or your company to get an account and to use it for multiple projects.
Regarding context.io, i didn't try it, but it seems that is an api for email and it should work, you can give it a try and see if the setup is easy to do, also keep in mind to test it in CI also if you are using any CI server like Jenkins.

Comment: Hi , thanks . I am tempted to use the disposable email systems like mailinator but its not free to get private account . And i dont have an option to but. Correct me if I am wrong , can I use context.io in this scenario ? But i think that it too requires imap settings so we will again require credentials.

Comment: Ok Thanks Lauda , the application is supporting email alias . .Going with that option!